# Can't access second controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have created twe separate controller one for `admin` and one for `front-end` i can access front end controller and can access it functions but when i try to access the admin controller i can't i am using `.htacess` file to rewrite the url .My url looks like that `http://localhost/bookstore/index`.

**Front-end controller:**

```
<?php 
class Bookstore extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','form','file','cookie','captcha'));
        $this->load->library(array('session','pagination','form_validation'));
        $this->load->model('bkmodel');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

**Admin-Controller :**

```
class Adminstore extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','form','file','cookie','captcha'));
        $this->load->library(array('session','pagination','form_validation'));
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
    }

   public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/index');
    }
}
```

Route file look like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "bookstore";
$route['(:any)'] = "bookstore/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

And i am stuck here that why the second controller is not working please point out my mistake so i can procced further one more thing when i want to access admin my url is like this `http://localhost/bookstore/adminstore/index` and it say 404 page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another routing rule before that "any" rule which redirects pretty much everything. So, something like this should work:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "bookstore";
$route['adminstore/(:any)'] = "adminstore/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "bookstore/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Remember, rules are checked in order, from top to bottom, so anything less specific/global should go at the top. "any" rules should be at the very bottom.

Comment: I wrote it from the top of my head, so it's not tested. You might need to tweak it to suit your admin controller, but that's the concept you should follow.

Comment: awesome your click and idea is @Shomz